# Moving Data From One Table To Set Of Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am preparing to move data from an existing table, to a set of new tables.  The old table, which I inherited, was constantly growing (in columns), and this new 
set was developed to try to accomodate the growth.  This data move will move data already entered into the old table into the new 'system' of tables.

I've come up with a rough logic plan and some code, but, as I'm pretty new to something this in-depth in SQL Server, I appreciate input and any help on the best 
course of action.

Here's my basic outline, not necessarily syntatically correct (due to my inexperience), but it helps illustrate the steps needed.  Would it be possible to do everything in this outline, in a single loop, or would I need to break this down into smaller actions?

1. Loop through Obj_Out_Old table, and copy data from it...

a. Get Obj_Out_Old.CourseID and put into Objectives.CourseID

b. Get Obj_Out_Old.Objective and put into Objectives.Objective

c. Loop through outcome columns - begin

--Explanation of Course Year and Course Semester:

--Check year in the Obj_Out_Old.CourseID (the last 2 digits - e.g. "79991208", where "08" means "2008"),

--Check semester in the Obj_Out_Old.CourseID (the 6th digit - e.g. if it equals "1" then "fall", if it equals "2" then "spring")

--to see which OutcomeID to get from the Outcomes table.

--code to get OutcomeYear and OutcomeSemester (below):

```
    --If (CourseID year = 2002 and CourseID semester = 'fall') OR (CourseID year > 2002 and CourseID year < 2004) OR (CourseID year = 2004 and 

CourseID semester = 'spring')
    --...translated....
    If ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 02) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 1))
    OR 
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) > 02) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) < 04))
    OR
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 04) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 2))

    Then 

    @OutcomeYear='2002'
    @OutcomeSemester='fall'

    End If

    --If (CourseID year = 2004 and CourseID semester = 'fall') OR (CourseID year > 2004 and CourseID year < 2008) OR (CourseID year = 2007 and CourseID semester = 

'fall')
    --...translated....  
    If ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 04) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 1))
    OR 
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) > 04) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) < 08))
    OR
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 07) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 1))

    Then

    @OutcomeYear='2004'
    @OutcomeSemester='fall'

    End If


    --If (CourseID year = 2008 and CourseID semester = 'spring') OR (CourseID year = 2008 and CourseID semester = 'fall') OR (CourseID year > 2008 and CourseID 

year < 2011) OR (CourseID year = 2011 and CourseID 

    --semester = 'spring')
    --...translated....
    If ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 08) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 2))
    OR 
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 08) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 1))
    OR 
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) > 08) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) < 11))
    OR
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 11) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 2))

    Then

    @OutcomeYear='2008'
    @OutcomeSemester='spring'

    End If


    --If (CourseID year = 2011 and CourseID semester = 'fall') OR (CourseID year > 2011 and CourseID year < 2013) OR (CourseID year = 2013 and CourseID semester = 

'spring')
    --...translated....
    If ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 11) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 1))
    OR 
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) > 11) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) < 13))
    OR
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 13) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 2))

    Then

    @OutcomeYear='2011'
    @OutcomeSemester='fall'

    End If


    --If (CourseID year = 2013 and CourseID semester = 'fall') OR (CourseID year > 2013 and CourseID year < 2015) OR (CourseID year = 2015 and CourseID semester = 

'spring')
    --...translated....
    If ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 13) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 1))
    OR 
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) > 13) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) < 15))
    OR
    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),7,2) AS INT) = 15) AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CourseID AS VARCHAR),6,1) = 2))

    Then

    @OutcomeYear='2013'
    @OutcomeSemester='fall'

    End If
```

--Once you find the outcomes set, 
--match the Outcome Number in the column name (from Obj_Out_Old table) with the Outcomes.OutcomeNumber

--Explanation of Outcome Number in the column name (from Obj_Out_Old table):
--If column name has "_a" in the title, then it is classified as OutcomeType "General" in the Outcomes table.
--For example, the column Obj_Out_Old.Out1_a would be Outcomes.OutcomeType="General", Outcomes.OutcomeNumber="1"
--Thus, the "_a" suffix is dropped (not carried over to new tables)

```
Get Outcome Number (in the Column Name, e.g. "Out1" with "1" being the Outcome Number) 

@Old_Table_Outcome_Number=[Outcome Number from column name]



    ~~~~~~~
    If (no '_a' in the column title) AND ((@OutcomeYear='2002' AND @OutcomeSemester='fall') OR (@OutcomeYear='2004' AND @OutcomeSemester='fall') OR 

(@OutcomeYear='2008' AND @OutcomeSemester='spring') OR 

    (@OutcomeYear='2011' AND @OutcomeSemester='fall') OR (@OutcomeYear='2013' AND @OutcomeSemester='fall'))

    Then

    @OutcomeType='Specific'

    Else If ('_a' in the column title) AND (@OutcomeYear='2008' AND @OutcomeSemester='spring')

    Then

    @OutcomeType='General'

    End If
    ~~~~~~~
```

--

```
--get Outcomes.ID
Select * from Outcomes 
WHERE
Outcomes.OutcomeNumber=@Old_Table_Outcome_Number
AND
Outcomes.OutcomeVersionYear=@OutcomeYear
AND
Outcomes.OutcomeVersionSemester=@OutcomeSemester
AND
Outcomes.OutcomeType=@OutcomeType
```

--

```
--Get Outcome Value

Get Outcome Value from Obj_Out_Old.[Current Outcome Column]
@Old_Table_Outcome_Value=Obj_Out_Old.[Current Outcome Column]


If (the column does not have "P" as the 4th character in the column name,  AND the column's value has either "N" "C" "P" or "N/A" values) 

Then
@NonPriorityVar=@Old_Table_Outcome_Value

End If

If (the column has "P" as the 4th character in the column name AND the column's value has either 0 or 1)

Then
@PriorityVar='Priority'
```

d. Put Outcomes.OutcomeID into Obj_Out table

e. Get Objectives.ID (from step a and b) and put into Obj_Out (same row as step d).

f. Get Obj_Out.ID (from row in step d).

g. Get Outcome Value (from step 4) 
and match to NCP table.

```
If @NonPriorityVar <> '' then

Select ID from NCP 
WHERE
NCP_Descr=@NonPriorityVar 
End If

--...or NCP_Priority table
If @PriorityVar<>'' then 

Select ID FROM NCP_Priority 
WHERE
NCP_Priority_Desc=@PriorityVar
End If
```

h. Put NCP.ID into NCP_Out.NCP_ID

i. If Outcomes table row has a priority as "true," then 
put NCP_Priority.ID (where NCP_Priority.Description="true" - from step 8a.) into 
NCP_Out.

Priority_ID=NCP_Priority.ID (from step g.)

NCP_Out.NCP_Priority_Value="true"

j. Put Obj_Out.ID (from step 6) 
into NCP_Out.ObjOutID

k. Repeat process for next row of Obj_Out_Old  table.

The tables are scripted (below):

```
--The existing table (ObjOut_Old) - 
--I've included several rows of sample data, to illustrate:

--==================


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Objective] [text] NULL,
    [Out1] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out3] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out4] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out5] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out6] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out7] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out8] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out9] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out10] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out11] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out12] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out13] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out14] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out15] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [OutP1] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP2] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP3] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP4] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP5] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP6] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP7] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP8] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP9] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP10] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP11] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP12] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP13] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP14] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP15] [bit] NULL,
    [Out1_a] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out2_a] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Out3_a] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [OutP1_a] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP2_a] [bit] NULL,
    [OutP3_a] [bit] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Obj_Out_Old] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] ([ID], [CourseID], [Objective], [Out1], [Out2], [Out3], [Out4], [Out5], [Out6], [Out7], [Out8], [Out9], [Out10], [Out11], [Out12], 

[Out13], [Out14], [Out15], [OutP1], [OutP2], [OutP3], [OutP4], [OutP5], [OutP6], [OutP7], [OutP8], [OutP9], [OutP10], [OutP11], [OutP12], [OutP13], [OutP14], 

[OutP15], [Out1_a], [Out2_a], [Out3_a], [OutP1_a], [OutP2_a], [OutP3_a], [LastUpdate], [Date_Created]) VALUES (26, 78442304, N'Identifies', N'C', N'C', N'N/A', 

N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, N'N/A', N'N/A', 

N'N/A', 0, 0, 0, CAST(0x000095FC00F61800 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] ([ID], [CourseID], [Objective], [Out1], [Out2], [Out3], [Out4], [Out5], [Out6], [Out7], [Out8], [Out9], [Out10], [Out11], [Out12], 

[Out13], [Out14], [Out15], [OutP1], [OutP2], [OutP3], [OutP4], [OutP5], [OutP6], [OutP7], [OutP8], [OutP9], [OutP10], [OutP11], [OutP12], [OutP13], [OutP14], 

[OutP15], [Out1_a], [Out2_a], [Out3_a], [OutP1_a], [OutP2_a], [OutP3_a], [LastUpdate], [Date_Created]) VALUES (117, 77132204, N'Develop', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', 

N'N', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N', N'N/A', N'N', N'N/A', N'N', N'N/A', N'N', N'N/A', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 

CAST(0x000095FE00EA8EE0 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] ([ID], [CourseID], [Objective], [Out1], [Out2], [Out3], [Out4], [Out5], [Out6], [Out7], [Out8], [Out9], [Out10], [Out11], [Out12], 

[Out13], [Out14], [Out15], [OutP1], [OutP2], [OutP3], [OutP4], [OutP5], [OutP6], [OutP7], [OutP8], [OutP9], [OutP10], [OutP11], [OutP12], [OutP13], [OutP14], 

[OutP15], [Out1_a], [Out2_a], [Out3_a], [OutP1_a], [OutP2_a], [OutP3_a], [LastUpdate], [Date_Created]) VALUES (123, 78422204, N'Strengthen', N'N/A', N'C', N'N', 

N'N', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'', N'', N'N/A', N'C', N'N/A', N'C', N'N', N'N/A', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CAST

(0x000095FE00F58B60 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] ([ID], [CourseID], [Objective], [Out1], [Out2], [Out3], [Out4], [Out5], [Out6], [Out7], [Out8], [Out9], [Out10], [Out11], [Out12], 

[Out13], [Out14], [Out15], [OutP1], [OutP2], [OutP3], [OutP4], [OutP5], [OutP6], [OutP7], [OutP8], [OutP9], [OutP10], [OutP11], [OutP12], [OutP13], [OutP14], 

[OutP15], [Out1_a], [Out2_a], [Out3_a], [OutP1_a], [OutP2_a], [OutP3_a], [LastUpdate], [Date_Created]) VALUES (124, 78422204, N'develop', N'', N'C', N'C', N'C', 

N'C', N'C', N'N/A', N'C', N'C', N'N/A', N'C', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'C', N'C', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CAST

(0x000095FE00F5D1B0 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] ([ID], [CourseID], [Objective], [Out1], [Out2], [Out3], [Out4], [Out5], [Out6], [Out7], [Out8], [Out9], [Out10], [Out11], [Out12], 

[Out13], [Out14], [Out15], [OutP1], [OutP2], [OutP3], [OutP4], [OutP5], [OutP6], [OutP7], [OutP8], [OutP9], [OutP10], [OutP11], [OutP12], [OutP13], [OutP14], 

[OutP15], [Out1_a], [Out2_a], [Out3_a], [OutP1_a], [OutP2_a], [OutP3_a], [LastUpdate], [Date_Created]) VALUES (127, 78242204, N'concepts', N'C', N'C', N'N/A', 

N'N/A', N'C', N'N/A', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N/A', N'N', N'N/A', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 

NULL, CAST(0x000095FF008D2CA0 AS DateTime), NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] OFF
/****** Object:  Default [DF__AMS_Conte__Date___3AC340F7]    Script Date: 05/16/2014 12:03:31 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__AMS_Conte__Date___3AC340F7]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Created]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_Obj_Out_Old_AMS_Courses]    Script Date: 05/16/2014 12:03:31 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Obj_Out_Old_AMS_Courses] FOREIGN KEY([CourseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AMS_Courses] ([CourseID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out_Old] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Obj_Out_Old_AMS_Courses]
GO



--///////////////////


--The new tables (6):
--//////////////////


/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Objectives]    Script Date: 05/12/2014 10:27:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Objectives](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Objective] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Objectives] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Objectives]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Objectives_AMS_Courses] FOREIGN KEY([CourseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AMS_Courses] ([CourseID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Objectives] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Objectives_AMS_Courses]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Objectives] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Objectives_Date_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Created]
GO




/////////////

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Outcomes]    Script Date: 05/12/2014 10:27:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Outcomes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OutcomeGroup] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OutcomeType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OutcomeNumber] [int] NULL,
    [OutcomeName] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [OutcomeDescription] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [OutcomeVersionYear] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OutcomeVersionSemester] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Outcomes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Outcomes] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Outcomes_Date_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Created]
GO





/////////////

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Obj_Out]    Script Date: 05/12/2014 10:27:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectiveID] [int] NULL,
    [OutcomeID] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Obj_Out] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Obj_Out_Objectives] FOREIGN KEY([ObjectiveID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Objectives] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Obj_Out_Objectives]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Obj_Out_Outcomes] FOREIGN KEY([OutcomeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Outcomes] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Obj_Out_Outcomes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Out] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Obj_Out_Date_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Created]
GO



/////////////

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[NCP_Out]    Script Date: 05/12/2014 10:32:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Out](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ObjOutID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NCP_ID] [int] NULL,
    [NCP_Value] [bit] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NCP_Out] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Out]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NCP_Out_NCP] FOREIGN KEY([NCP_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[NCP] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Out] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_NCP_Out_NCP]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Out]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NCP_Out_Obj_Out] FOREIGN KEY([ObjOutID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Obj_Out] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Out] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_NCP_Out_Obj_Out]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Out] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_NCP_Out_Date_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Created]
GO




/////////////

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[NCP]    Script Date: 05/12/2014 10:26:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NCP](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NCP_Descr] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NCP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NCP] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_NCP_Date_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Created]
GO


///////////

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[NCP_Priority]    Script Date: 05/13/2014 17:16:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Priority](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NCP_Priority_Descr] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date_Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NCP_Priority] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NCP_Priority] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_NCP_Priority_Date_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Created]
GO
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this suits Code Review better than SO. The amount of code is also just too much.

Comment: You also need to remember that you're dealing with a database, not code.  Think in sets instead of loops.  Query all your id's and push them into another table.

Comment: And as @PatrickHofman says, narrow this question down to one that can be answered succinctly.  Way too much to consume here.